# Какие есть графические библиотеки под jav'у? (Желательно не навороченные)

Tags: java, разработка-игр, поиск-библиотек, 2d

Я хочу написать свою простенькую 2D игру вместе со своей собственной физикой, но для этого мне требуется максимально простая и не перегруженная функционалом графическая библиотека. Есть ли такая?

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Вы верно использованли метку поиска-библиотек, но приведите ваш вопрос к следующим требованиям _"Чётко опишите задачу и требования к библиотеке. Если известны библиотеки, которые не подошли, перечислите их и поясните, почему именно они не подошли. Вопросы "какая библиотека лучше" являются оффтопиком в случае отсутствия чётких критериев сравнения."_ Сейчас ваш вопрос является офтопиком

Answer (score 3):

С комментарием [Дмитрия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209304/dmitry) согласен, но всё равно поддержу, так как мне понравился вопрос, в целом. Ниже расписал всё, что смог подобрать на данный момент для Вас. Могу предложить такие варианты для Вашего потенциального решения задач:

### **Под разработку 2D-игр:**

---

1.[LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org):

*LWJGL* — это библиотека Java, обеспечивающая кросс-платформенный доступ к популярным собственным API-интерфейсам, полезным при разработке графических (OpenGL, Vulkan), аудио (OpenAL) и приложений параллельных вычислений (OpenCL). Этот доступ является прямым и высокопроизводительным, но в то же время он заключен в типобезопасный и удобный для пользователя уровень, соответствующий экосистеме Java.

2. [Отдельный список библиотек под разработку 2D-игр](https://github.com/topics/java-2d-game).

### **Графические 2D-библиотеки:**

---

1. [JFreeChart](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) ([Github источник](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart)):

*JFreeChart* — это бесплатная 100% библиотека диаграмм Java, которая позволяет разработчикам легко отображать диаграммы профессионального качества в своих приложениях. Обширный набор функций *JFreeChart* включает в себя:

- последовательный и хорошо документированный API, поддерживающий широкий спектр типов диаграмм;
- гибкая конструкция, которую легко расширить и которая предназначена как для серверных, так и для клиентских приложений;
- поддержка многих типов вывода, включая компоненты Swing и JavaFX, файлы изображений (включая PNG и JPEG) и форматы файлов векторной графики (включая PDF, EPS и SVG);
- JFreeChart — это программное обеспечение с открытым исходным кодом или, точнее, бесплатное программное обеспечение. Оно распространяется на условиях лицензии GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), которая разрешает использование в проприетарных приложениях.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. [GRAphing Library (*GRAL*)](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/data/9781787122536/9/ch09lvl1sec79/plotting-a-2d-sine-graph):

Бесплатная библиотека графов Java под названием GRAphing Library (GRAL) для построения двумерного синусоидального графика. Во многих случаях синусоидальные графики могут быть особенно полезны для специалистов по данным, поскольку они представляют собой тригонометрические графики, которые можно использовать для моделирования колебаний данных (например, используя данные о температуре для создания модели, которая прогнозирует время в течение года, когда местоположение будет).

3. [JChart2D](https://mobile.aau.at/selforganized-wiki/index.php/Data_Visualization_with_Java):

*JChart2D* — это минималистичная библиотека диаграмм в реальном времени. Она предназначена для отображения нескольких трассировок, состоящих из точек трассировки. JChart2D основан на одном настраиваемом виджете Swing: Chart2D. Это JComponent, который можно добавить в пользовательский интерфейс Java Swing. Поэтому базовые знания Java awt и Swing, а также информация, представленная на этом сайте, будут полезны. Если даны базовые знания о свинге и awt, JChart2D очень легко понять и использовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вспомогательные ссылки с дополнительными библиотеками:

1. [Top 5 Java Chart Projects](https://www.libhunt.com/l/java/topic/charts)
2. [Open Source Windows Charting Libraries](https://sourceforge.net/directory/charting-libraries/windows/)
3. [2D/3D Vertical Bar Graph API Library (Java Bean) 4.6](https://www.freshdevices.com/16536/details-2d-3d-vertical-bar-graph-api-library-java-bean-.html)
4. [JChart2D](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jchart2d/)
5. [What is the best open-source java charting library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/265777/8370915)
6. [Code a 2D Game Engine using Java - Full Course for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=025QFeZfeyM)
7. [Как сделать 2D Java игру](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=om59cwR7psI)